# push/pop segmentation fault in simple multiplication function

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

my teacher is doing a crash course in assembly with us, and I have no experience in it whatsoever. I am supposed to write a simple function that takes four variables and calculates (x+y)-(z+a) and then prints out the answer. I know it's a simple problem, but after hours of research I am getting no where, any push in the right direction would be very helpful! I do need to use the stack, as I have more things to add to the program once I get past this point, and will have a lot of variables to store. I am compiling using nasm and gcc, in linux. (x86 64)

(side question, my '3' isn't showing up in register r10, but I am in linux so this should be the correct register... any ideas?)

Here is my code so far:

```
    global main

    extern printf

segment .data

    mulsub_str  db  "(%ld * %ld) - (%ld * %ld) = %ld",10,0

    data            dq  1, 2, 3, 4
segment .text

main:

    call multiplyandsubtract
    pop r9
    mov rdi, mulsub_str
    mov rsi, [data]
    mov rdx, [data+8]
    mov r10, [data+16]
    mov r8, [data+24]
    mov rax, 0
    call printf

    ret



multiplyandsubtract:

    ;;multiplies first function
    mov rax, [data]
    mov rdi, [data+8]
    mul rdi
    mov rbx, rdi
    push rbx

    ;;multiplies second function
    mov rax, [data+16]
    mov rsi, [data+24]
    mul rsi
    mov rbx, rsi
    push rbx

    ;;subtracts function 2 from function 1
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    sub rdi, rsi
    push rdi
    ret
```

Comment: `x+y` is addition, not multiplication, although that's not really relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> push in the right direction

Nice pun!

Your problem is that you apparently don't seem to know that `ret` is using the stack for the return address. As such `push rdi; ret` will just go to the address in `rdi` and not return to your caller. Since that is unlikely to be a valid code address, you get a nice segfault.

To return values from functions just leave the result in a register, standard calling conventions normally use `rax`. Here is a possible version:

```
    global main

    extern printf

segment .data

    mulsub_str  db  "(%ld * %ld) - (%ld * %ld) = %ld",10,0

    data            dq  1, 2, 3, 4
segment .text

main:
    sub rsp, 8
    call multiplyandsubtract
    mov r9, rax
    mov rdi, mulsub_str
    mov rsi, [data]
    mov rdx, [data+8]
    mov r10, [data+16]
    mov r8, [data+24]
    mov rax, 0
    call printf
    add rsp, 8

    ret



multiplyandsubtract:

    ;;multiplies first function
    mov rax, [data]
    mov rdi, [data+8]
    mul rdi
    mov rbx, rdi
    push rbx

    ;;multiplies second function
    mov rax, [data+16]
    mov rsi, [data+24]
    mul rsi
    mov rbx, rsi
    push rbx

    ;;subtracts function 2 from function 1
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    sub rdi, rsi
    mov rax, rdi
    ret
```

PS: notice I have also fixed the stack alignment as per the ABI. `printf` is known to be picky about that too.

Answer (score 0):

To return more than 64b from subroutine (`rax` is not enough), you can optionally drop the whole standard ABI convention (or actually follow it, there's surely a well defined way how to return more than 64b from subroutines), and use other registers until you ran out of them.

And once you ran out of spare return registers (or when you desperately want to use stack memory), you can follow the way C++ compilers do:

```
    SUB    rsp,<return_data_size + alignment>
    CALL   subroutine
    ...
    MOV    al,[rsp + <offset>]   ; to access some value from returned data
      ; <offset> = 0 to return_data_size-1, as defined by you when defining
      ; the memory layout for returned data structure
    ...
    ADD    rsp,<return_data_size + alignment> ; restore stack pointer

subroutine:
    MOV    al,<result_value_1>
    MOV    [rsp + 8 + <offset>],al  ; store it into allocated stack space
      ; the +8 is there to jump beyond return address, which was pushed
      ; at stack by "CALL" instruction. If you will push more registers/data
      ; at the stack inside the subroutine, you will have either to recalculate
      ; all offsets in following code, or use 32b C-like function prologue:

    PUSH   rbp
    MOV    rbp,rsp
    MOV    [rbp + 16 + <offset>],al ; now all offsets are constant relative to rbp
    ... other code ...
    ; epilogue code restoring stack
    MOV    rsp,rbp  ; optional, when you did use RSP and didn't restore it yet
    POP    rbp
    RET
```

So during executing the instructions of subroutine, the stack memory layout is like this:

```
rsp -> current_top_of_stack (some temporary push/pop as needed)
+x     ...
rbp -> original rbp value (if prologue/epilogue code was used)
+8     return address to caller
+16    allocated space for returning values
+16+return_data_size
       ... padding to have rsp correctly aligned by ABI requirements ...
+16+return_data_size+alignment
       ... other caller stack data or it's own stack frame/return address ...
```

---

I'm not going to check how ABI defines it, because I'm too lazy, plus I hope this answer is understandable for you to explain the principle, so you will recognize which way the ABI works and adjust...

---

Then again, I would highly recommend to use rather many shorter simpler subroutines returning only single value (in `rax/eax/ax/al`), whenever possible, try to follow the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). The above way will force you to define some return-data-structure, which may be too much hassle, if it's just some temporary thing and can be split into single-value subroutines instead (if performance is endangered, then probably inlining the whole subroutine will outperform even the logic of grouped returned values and single CALL).